# Mixing vectors with different length

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a 2 column vector with different lengths `y1` and `y2`. I want to mixed them together in one matrix.

This matrix should have `y1` and `y2` as a rows, but they have different lengths. Is it possible to add 0 to shorter vector that it has the same length as longer one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this, here is one:

```
>> y1 = [1;2;3;4;5];
>> y2 = [7;8;9];
>> z = zeros(2, max(length(y1), length(y2)));
>> z(1, 1:length(y1)) = y1;
>> z(2, 1:length(y2)) = y2

z =

     1     2     3     4     5
     7     8     9     0     0
```

Comment: It's ok, but I want to mix the rows a little for example:
row1 = y1+2*y2
row2= 0.5y1+2.3*y2
I can just duplicate z and mix z with duplicated z, but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

[`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) does that easily:

```
vec2mat([y1; y2], max(numel(y1), numel(y2)))
```